# In Eclipse, how do I refresh the icon decorators (per-file 1+ warning, 1+ error) in my Project Explorer?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, in the Project Explorer pane, each Java file will have an icon decorator, indicating whether that file has 1+ compilation errors, or 1+ compilation warnings.

I often find that these icon decorators are out of date with my latest file changes.

How can I force them to be up to date?

I try right-clicking on the project's top-level directory and selecting Refresh, but that doesn't help.  Neither does restarting Eclipse.

I realize that one alternative is to use the Markers pane, but that gets me the entire list of all warnings/errors across all files.  I'd rather know, see visually, which files have problems and which are clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said which language you are using and whether autobuilds are on or off.

In general, problem markers are only added and removed by your project's *builder*. If you are using Java, for example, that language has full automatic incremental build support, so the markers update whenever you save a file. Not all languages enjoy this; you may need to explicitly rebuild your project(s) to force an update.

If you believe a marker is out-of-date, or just want to hide it, it's usually safe to delete it from the Markers view; the relevant builder will reinstate it if necessary next time it runs.